# Ubuntu 12.04 connected to wireless network but internet not working

Tags: wireless, networking

I can connect to my house's wireless network just fine, but when I'm connected I can't browse the web. Firefox starts connecting to a site and then just poops out. This doesn't happen on my roommates' computers (running Windows) or on our 3DSes, so I know it's just my laptop.

(Edited to remove irrelevant information)

[This other user's answer solved my problem.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150212/wireless-connected-but-no-internet-connection-ubuntu-12-04)

I would post this as an answer, but the site keeps converting it to a comment. Thank you for all the suggestions, though!

Comment: Okay, I've done that.

Comment: Done. (Do I need to comment when I've done it, or can you track edits?)

Comment: You sure the password is correct and that 192.168.0.1 is your router IP? If you are sure, then run `sudo dhclient wlan0`. And no, any update has to be commented or I don't get a message.

Comment: The password and router IP are correct. Post edited with this output.

Answer (score 0):

You can open this file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

And add this line:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

Reboot to see if it works.

If not, it may be this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/945379

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't seem to have made any difference. To clarify, my problem isn't with the wireless connection itself. It connects just fine. I just can't browse the web while connected.